# How do I get the utc offset from an address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, gmaps4rails, timezone-offset

I have a RoR application where I store locations using gmaps4rails. Based on the address of the location, I'd like to guess the UTC offset ("+00:00", "-05:00", ..).
Is it possible or I have to ask users (and trust them) to set the correct timezone offset?

By the way, I know that there are some places where the timezone offset may change during the year. In this case, I should use the zone name instead of the offset. Is there a gem that helps to deal with these issues?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you checked [timezone gem](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone) ?

Comment: What kind of address do you have? IP addresses? Coordinates? Postal addresses?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to extract timezone from address but to convert time to different timezone; rails has method `in_time_zone`. So you could do like `Time.now.in_time_zone('Tokyo')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a time zone from a location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location)

Comment: Thank you Matt for the link, it is very useful. I've tried the google_timezone gem which asks Google Timezone Web Service and it answers to all my needs.
The addresses I use are latitude/longitude.
`in_time_zone` will be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geolocate the address to lat/lon coordinates using any number of web services for this.  Then see the options in [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location)  The Ruby gem that Yevgeniy mentioned is listed there, along with other options.

Don't try to get an *offset* for the location - it could change periodically for DST.  Get the *time zone* instead, such as `Asia/Singapore` or `America/New_York`.  Then use that to determine the offset for a particular point in time.

See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score -2):

Even if you get the solution, it is better to ask them from user. If user in the US wants to see his/her datetime according to timezone in Singapore (because that is his/her homeown), he/she should be shown it like that.

Comment: Who said it was for the user?  He asked how to get the time zone of a location.  Perhaps he just wants to know what time it is at a customer's location based on their address.  The use case is valid.

Comment: The address I store is a place where the user and his/her friends should meet. So, the best solution in this case is to use the local time.

Comment: @techvineet, your alternative is interesting but it does not really answer the question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @techvineet, sorry for you but I don't have enough reputation to vote down!